# Geometric models for the classifying spaces of the spin and string covers of the orthogonal, symplectic, and symmetric groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

$\newcommand{\oUConf}{\widehat{\mathrm{UConf}}}\newcommand{\UConf}{\mathrm{UConf}}\newcommand{\oGr}{\widehat{\mathrm{Gr}}}\newcommand{\Gr}{\mathrm{Gr}}\newcommand{\SO}{\mathrm{SO}}\newcommand{\Spin}{\mathrm{Spin}}\newcommand{\String}{\mathrm{String}}\newcommand{\U}{\mathrm{U}}\newcommand{\SU}{\mathrm{SU}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathrm{O}}\newcommand{\Sp}{\mathrm{Sp}}\newcommand{\Mp}{\mathrm{Mp}}$We can describe the classifying spaces of the groups $\O_n$, $\SO_n$, $\U_n$, $\Sp_n$, $\Sigma_n$, and $A_n$ as follows:

- $\mathrm{B}\O_n$, $\mathrm{B}\U_n$, $\mathrm{B}\Sp_n$ are the Grassmanians of $n$-planes $\Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$, $\Gr_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)$, and $\Gr_n(\mathbb{H}^\infty)$;
- $\mathrm{B}\SO_n$ is the Grassmanians of *oriented* $n$-planes $\oGr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$;
- $\mathrm{B}\Sigma_n$ is the unordered configuration space $\UConf_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ of $n$ points on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$;
- $\mathrm{B}A_n$ is the space $\oUConf_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ whose points are [$n$ points on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ together with an orientation of their spanned $n$-plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30113);

Are there similar "geometric" descriptions for $\mathrm{B}\Spin_n$ and $\mathrm{B}\String_n$?

What about $\mathrm{B}\SU_n$ (is there a [more explicit description than "the $3$-connected cover of $\mathrm{B}\U_n$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2850463)?), [$\mathrm{B}\Mp_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group), [$\mathrm{B}\widetilde{A}_n$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_cover_of_alternating_group), and [$\mathrm{B}\mathcal{A}_n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09192)?

Comment: (Here I mean "geometric" in the same sense of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33834))

Comment: BSU_n classifies complex vector spaces (in C^infty) with an isomorphism Lambda^n V = C. This is directly comparable to the definition of BSO_n --- this is no more than a complex orientation of V. I don't know what a spin structure on a vector space is but if I did I would tell you that BSpin_n classifies oriented n-dim vector spaces (in R^infty) with a spin structure.

Comment: Your question appears to be essentially a subset of this Community Wiki question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56363/list-of-classifying-spaces-and-covers

Comment: @mme Thanks, this is super nice!

Comment: @RyanBudney I think there's value in asking this separately, mostly because of focus (while the possible \*answers\* here would form a subset of those there, the same is not true for the question: there's e.g. no mention of BSpin, BString, etc. in the question body there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\def\B{{\rm B}} \def\bB{{\bf B}} \def\Spin{{\rm Spin}} \def\String{{\rm String}} \B\Spin(n)$, simply equip the $n$-planes with a [spin structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122748/what-is-a-spinor-structure/122798#122798), as originally proposed by Stolz and Teichner.

For $\B\String(n)$, equip the $n$-planes with a string structure,
as described in a [paper by Douglas and Henriques](http://andreghenriques.com/PDF/TringWP.pdf).

Also, I am not sure what the intended difference between $\B$ and $\bB$ is,
but if $\bB$ does refer to the stack version of these classifying spaces,
then the above constructions continue to work perfectly well
for stacks: to a smooth manifold $S$ assign the groupoid respectively 2-groupoid of vector bundles with base $S$ and whose fibers are equipped with a spin respectively string structure.

This yields the stacks $\bB\Spin(n)$ and $\bB\String(n)$, and applying the shape functor to these stacks yields the classifying spaces $\B\Spin(n)$ and $\B\String(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri, this is very nice! Is it correct to say that similar descriptions will work for the other spaces above (e.g. a point of $\mathrm{B}\widetilde{A}_n$ being $n$-points in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ together with a spin structure on their spanned $n$-plane)? (I didn't mean anything special when writing $\mathbf{B}$ instead of $\mathrm{B}$)

Comment: @Emily: I expect it to be true, but I do not think anybody wrote it up.  In fact, even the claims about BSpin and BString do not appear to be written up.

Comment: ＠DmitriPavlov Thanks!